# Suspicious connections by Firefox

Tags: firefox

In the middle of the night, I happened to look at Firefox's network traffic and I found this odd set of connections to `k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan` Does anyone know what this is? In all there were 295 such connections. When I started using the browser again, all of a sudden all these connections were closed. I have Ublock origin enabled.

The domain `k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan` [comes up as associated with](https://domain.glass/epimetheus.navigator-lxa.mail.com) mail.com

```
firefox-e  1753  1955 HTML5\x20             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  1955 HTML5\x20             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  1955 HTML5\x20             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  1959 ProcessHa             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  1959 ProcessHa             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  1959 ProcessHa             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  1959 ProcessHa             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  1959 ProcessHa             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2009 mozStorag             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2009 mozStorag             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2009 mozStorag             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2009 mozStorag             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2009 mozStorag             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2010 MediaMana             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2010 MediaMana             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2010 MediaMana             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2010 MediaMana             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2010 MediaMana             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2011 mozStorag             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2011 mozStorag             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2011 mozStorag             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2011 mozStorag             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2011 mozStorag             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2029 ImgDecode             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2029 ImgDecode             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2029 ImgDecode             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2029 ImgDecode             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2029 ImgDecode             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2091 DOM\x20Wo             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2091 DOM\x20Wo             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2091 DOM\x20Wo             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2091 DOM\x20Wo             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2091 DOM\x20Wo             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2097 mozStorag             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2097 mozStorag             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2097 mozStorag             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2097 mozStorag             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2097 mozStorag             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2102 mozStorag             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2102 mozStorag             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2102 mozStorag             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2102 mozStorag             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  2102 mozStorag             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3056 threaded-             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3056 threaded-             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3056 threaded-             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3056 threaded-             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3056 threaded-             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3199 VideoCapt             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3199 VideoCapt             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3199 VideoCapt             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3199 VideoCapt             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3199 VideoCapt             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3200 InotifyEv             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3200 InotifyEv             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3200 InotifyEv             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3200 InotifyEv             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  3200 InotifyEv             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  7509 DNS\x20Re             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  7509 DNS\x20Re             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  7509 DNS\x20Re             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  7509 DNS\x20Re             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  7509 DNS\x20Re             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  8560 speechd               myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  8560 speechd               myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  8560 speechd               myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  8560 speechd               myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753  8560 speechd               myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753 10535 Backgro~o             myself   64u     IPv4              60232        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39316->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753 10535 Backgro~o             myself   78u     IPv4              61597        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39298->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753 10535 Backgro~o             myself  115u     IPv4              60235        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39322->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753 10535 Backgro~o             myself  119u     IPv4              63372        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39310->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e  1753 10535 Backgro~o             myself  120u     IPv4              60236        0t0        TCP raspberrypi:39324->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: The detail that you were connected to mail.com would be a significant detail to include.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you can confirm an actual security issue, we can't do log analysis to work out whether there ***is*** a security issue. And, as it turns out, everything was innocent.

Answer (score 1):

> I wasn't able to get the full domain name ...
>
> ```
> .... ->k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan:https ...
> ```

This is the full domain name. The name though is something returned by doing a reverse DNS lookup and the server can claim anything here.

> [from comment]
> I did find this match for the domain which is not local: domain.glass/74.208.232.202

Interesting finding. A reverse lookup to this domain actually shows this domain name:

```
$ dig -x 74.208.232.202
...
202.232.208.74.in-addr.arpa. 6462 IN    PTR     k8s-poma-traefik-ext-fe-prod-iz1-lxa.poinfra.server.lan.
```

For a neighbor address of 74.208.232.201 it shows a similar `k8s-pocam-traefik-ext-fe-prod-us.poinfra.server.lan.`. Based on the prefix k8s these might be part of a kubernetes cluster.

Checking the ownership for these IP (information in the same link you gave) shows 1&1 IONOS and the certificate returned is for *.mail.com (202) and *.ui-portal.de - both domains owned by 1&1 and which are essential part of their public infrastructure. The certificates are valid and issued by a public CA DigiCert, which indicates that these systems are really part of 1&1 infrastructure.

So, for me it looks like that you've connected to innocent domains. It is unclear though why you connected to these domains, since no such context is known.

Comment: I did find this match for the domain which is not local: https://domain.glass/74.208.232.202

Comment: I had about 5 tabs open in Firefox. Only one of them was pointing to Mail.com which is 1&1. In that tab though, I was logged out of the mail service. I've seen this type of access before a few days ago. I'm a little concerned at the other content in the connection listing e.g. mozStorage, ImgDecode.

Comment: @asker13: Then this was caused by your access to mail.com - no matter if you were logged out or logged in. And mozStorage, ImgDecode ... are just several parts of Firefox, pretty normal. Just look at the ports and node id and you'll see that they actually share the same connections, i.e. there are many duplicates here.